# SWIG struct pointer as output parameter

Tags: python, c, swig

I have a struct:

```
struct some_struct_s {
   int arg1;
   int arg2;
};
```

I have a C function:

```
int func(some_struct_s *output);
```

Both are `%included` into my SWIG file.

I want `some_struct_s *output` to be treated like an output parameter.  Python example:

```
int_val, some_struct_output = func()
```

"Output parameters" is covered in the manual for POD-types (sec 10.1.3), but not for non-POD types.

How do I tell SWIG I want `some_struct_s *output` to be an output parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps_nn32):

> 11.5.7 "argout" typemap
>
> The "argout" typemap is used to return values from arguments. This is most commonly used to write wrappers for C/C++ functions that need to return multiple values. The "argout" typemap is almost always combined with an "in" typemap---possibly to ignore the input value....

Here's a complete example for your code (no error checking for brevity):

```
%module test

// Declare an input typemap that suppresses requiring any input and
// declare a temporary stack variable to hold the return data.
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) some_struct_s* (some_struct_s tmp) %{
    $1 = &tmp;
%}

// Declare an output argument typemap.  In this case, we'll use
// a tuple to hold the structure data (no error checking).
%typemap(argout) some_struct_s* (PyObject* o) %{
    o = PyTuple_New(2);
    PyTuple_SET_ITEM(o,0,PyLong_FromLong($1->arg1));
    PyTuple_SET_ITEM(o,1,PyLong_FromLong($1->arg2));
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,o);
%}

// Instead of a header file, we'll just declare this code inline.
// This includes the code in the wrapper, as well as telling SWIG
// to create wrappers in the target language.
%inline %{

struct some_struct_s {
   int arg1;
   int arg2;
};

int func(some_struct_s *output) {
    output->arg1 = 1;
    output->arg2 = 2;
    return 0;
}

%}
```

Demo below.  Note that the `int` return value of zero as well as the output parameter as  a tuple are returned as a list.

```
>>> import test
>>> test.func()
[0, (1, 2)]
```

If you don't want typemaps, you can also inject code to create the object and return it to hide it from the user:

```
%module test

%rename(_func) func; // Give the wrapper a different name

%inline %{

struct some_struct_s {
   int arg1;
   int arg2;
};

int func(struct some_struct_s *output)
{
    output->arg1 = 1;
    output->arg2 = 2;
    return 0;
}

%}

// Declare your interface
%pythoncode %{
def func():
    s = some_struct_s()
    r = _func(s)
    return r, s
%}
```

Demo:

```
>>> import test
>>> r, s = test.func()
>>> r
0
>>> s
<test.some_struct_s; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'some_struct_s *' at 0x000001511D70A880> >
>>> s.arg1
1
>>> s.arg2
2
```

You can make the typemap language agnostic if you carefully select SWIG macros:

```
%module test

%typemap(in,numinputs=0) struct some_struct_s *output %{
    $1 = malloc(sizeof(struct some_struct_s));
%}

%typemap(argout) struct some_struct_s* output {
    // The last parameter passes ownership of the pointer
    // to Python so it will be freed when the object's
    // reference count goes to zero.
    %append_output(SWIG_NewPointerObj($1, $1_descriptor, SWIG_POINTER_OWN));
}

%inline %{

struct some_struct_s {
   int arg1;
   int arg2;
};

int func(struct some_struct_s *output)
{
    output->arg1 = 1;
    output->arg2 = 2;
    return 0;
}

%}
```

Demo:

```
>>> import test
>>> r, s = test.func()
>>> r
0
>>> s
<test.some_struct_s; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'some_struct_s *' at 0x000001DD0425A700> >
>>> s.arg1
1
>>> s.arg2
2
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Without this, I have noticed that I can instantiate an empty `some_struct_s` on one line of code and pass it in.  When the function returns, the contents are non-opaque. This has the benefit of me not having to write a language-specific typemap.  I was hoping there was a way to signify the parameter should be at the end without having to write output language-specific api code for each element in an argout typemap. Should I give up hope?

Comment: @MichaelLabbé  haven't found a way without writing a typemap, but you can avoid language specifics by using some SWIG macros.  I'll update with an example.

Comment: @MarkTolonen  I noticed in the final example, that there is a malloc during typemap(in) without a free using typemap(freearg). Would there be a memory leak as a result?

Comment: @Maverickgugu The last parameter of `SWIG_newPointerObj()` is `own`.  The value `1` passes ownership to Python and it frees the pointer when the Python object's reference count goes to zero.  To verify this I built a debug version of the library and passed an invalid pointer to `SWIG_newPointerObj()`.  I called the function but didn't access the returned object.  When I exited Python it crashed due to trying to free the invalid pointer value.  Changing `own` to `0`  prevented the crash, since the pointer wasn't freed.

Comment: @Maverickgugu Updated the example to make the free clear.  SWIG had a named constant I could use.  Link to docs describing the `own` parameter: https://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn64