# SWIG wrap for Python a void function with an output reference to smart pointer parameter

Tags: python, c++, swig, swig-typemap

Along the lines of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53387538/swig-struct-pointer-as-output-parameter), suppose we have a C++ `struct S` and a function `makeS` which creates an instance of `S` and assigns it to a shared pointer `p`.  Here is a [self-contained running example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=436615986a6a9db9):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct S
{
    int x;
    
    S() { x = 0; std::cout << "S::S()\n"; }
 
    // Note: non-virtual destructor is OK here
    ~S() { std::cout << "S::~S()\n"; }
};
 
 
void makeS(std::shared_ptr<S> &p)
{
    p = std::make_shared<S>();
    p->x = 12;
}
 
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<S> p;
    makeS(p);
    std::cout << "x = " << p->x << "\n";
}
```

which outputs

```
S::S()
x = 12
S::~S()
```

How do we wrap `void makeS(std::shared_ptr<S> &p)` in SWIG for Python 3 so that, in Python, we can run

```
p = makeS()
```

and get a smart pointer to an instance of `S`?  In other words, how do we write the Python-based `%typemap` for `std::shared_ptr<S> &` so that we can write something like

```
%apply std::shared_ptr<S> &OUTPUT { std::shared_ptr<S> & }
```

and not get an error from SWIG that there is no typemap defined?

**UPDATE:** With input from Mark Tolonen below, I can add more detail but I am still stuck.  We have the following files:

**Widget.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Widget
{
    int x;
    
    Widget() { x = 0; std::cout << "Widget::Widget()\n"; }
 
    // Note: non-virtual destructor is OK here
    ~Widget() { std::cout << "Widget::~Widget()\n"; }
};
 
void makeWidget(std::shared_ptr<Widget> &p);
```

**Widget.cpp**

```
#include "Widget.h"

void makeWidget(std::shared_ptr<Widget> &p)
  {
    p = std::make_shared<Widget>();
    p->x = 12;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Widget.h"
 
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Widget> p;
    makeWidget(p);
    std::cout << "x = " << p->x << "\n";
}
```

From here I can execute (on Ubuntu):

```
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c Widget.cpp
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c main.cpp
g++ Widget.o main.o -o widget
widget
```

and get an output from running `widget` of

```
Widget::Widget()
x = 12
Widget::~Widget()
```

Next we create a wrap

**Widget.i**

```
%module Widget

%include <typemaps.i> // for OUTPUT
%include <std_shared_ptr.i>
%shared_ptr(Widget);

%{
#include "Widget.h"
%}

// Declare an input typemap that suppresses requiring any input.
%typemap(in, numinputs=0) std::shared_ptr<Widget>& %{
%}

// Declare an output argument typemap updates the shared pointer,
// converts it to a Python object, and appends it to the return value.
%typemap(argout) std::shared_ptr<Widget>& %{

  try { 
    PyObject* obj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(&arg1, $descriptor(std::shared_ptr<Widget>*), 0);
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, obj); }
  catch (...) {
    SWIG_fail;
  }

%}

%include "Widget.h"
```

Running

```
swig -c++ -python -o Widget_wrap.cpp Widget.i
```

will generate the following code in the new file

**Widget_wrap.cpp**:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_makeWidget(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  std::shared_ptr< Widget > *arg1 = 0 ;
  
  
  
  if (!SWIG_Python_UnpackTuple(args, "makeWidget", 0, 0, 0)) SWIG_fail;
  makeWidget(*arg1);
  resultobj = SWIG_Py_Void();
  
  
  try {
    PyObject* obj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(&arg1, SWIGTYPE_p_std__shared_ptrT_Widget_t, 0);
    resultobj = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput(resultobj, obj); 
  }
  catch (...) {
    SWIG_fail;
  }
  
  
  return resultobj;
fail:
  return NULL;
}
```

Notice that the variable `arg1` and call `makeWidget(*arg1);` were generated by Swig on its own and are not contained in the `typemap` in the .i file.  After a prior pass, I saw them and that is why I use `arg1` in the `typemap`.  We compile and build the `.so` file:

```
 g++ -O2 -fPIC -I/home/catskills/anaconda3/envs/trader/include/python3.10 -c Widget_wrap.cpp
 g++ -shared *Widget.o Widget_wrap.o -o _Widget.so
```

Unfortunately then loading and running this in Python gives a seg fault:

```
$ python
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Widget
>>> Widget.makeWidget()
Widget::Widget()
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**QUESTION:** How do we get rid of the seg fault?

**UPDATE 2:** To answer this question, I modified the example to the more usual case of writing a function that returns a result, rather than a void function with a result out parameter.  The resulting `Widget_wrap.cpp` gives some insight on how to wrap for the desired case.  The modified case is:

**Widget.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Widget
{
    int x;
    
    Widget() { x = 0; std::cout << "Widget::Widget()\n"; }
 
    // Note: non-virtual destructor is OK here
    ~Widget() { std::cout << "Widget::~Widget()\n"; }
};
 
std::shared_ptr<Widget> makeWidget();
```

**Widget.cpp**

```
#include "Widget.h"

std::shared_ptr<Widget> makeWidget()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Widget> p = std::make_shared<Widget>();
    p->x = 12;
    return p;
}
```

**Widget.i**

```
%module Widget

%include <std_shared_ptr.i>
%shared_ptr(Widget);

%{
#include "Widget.h"
%}

%include "Widget.h"
```

This produces:

**Widget_wrap.cpp**

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_makeWidget(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  std::shared_ptr< Widget > result;
  
  if (!SWIG_Python_UnpackTuple(args, "makeWidget", 0, 0, 0)) SWIG_fail;
  result = makeWidget();
  {
    std::shared_ptr<  Widget > *smartresult = result ? new std::shared_ptr<  Widget >(result) : 0;
    resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(smartresult), SWIGTYPE_p_std__shared_ptrT_Widget_t, SWIG_POINTER_OWN);
  }
  return resultobj;
fail:
  return NULL;
}
```

As we can see there is quite a fancy treatment of the conversion of the shared pointer into a Swig pointer.  If we then transplant that manually into the Widget_wrap.cpp of the original case, we get this:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_makeWidget(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  std::shared_ptr< Widget > result;

  if (!SWIG_Python_UnpackTuple(args, "makeWidget", 0, 0, 0)) SWIG_fail;
  makeWidget(result);
  {
    std::shared_ptr<  Widget > *smartresult = result ? new std::shared_ptr<  Widget >(result) : 0;
    resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(smartresult), SWIGTYPE_p_std__shared_ptrT_Widget_t, SWIG_POINTER_OWN);
  }
  return resultobj;
fail:
  return NULL;
}
```

If we build this and run it through this Python test program:

**test.py**

```
from Widget import *
x = makeWidget()
print(x)
y = makeWidget()
print(y)
```

We get a nice result:

```
$ python test.py
Widget::Widget()
<Widget.Widget; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::shared_ptr< Widget > *' at 0x7f05f6329f00> >
Widget::Widget()
<Widget.Widget; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::shared_ptr< Widget > *' at 0x7f05f61941e0> >
Widget::~Widget()
Widget::~Widget()
```

This leads to a final revised question (working on this next):

**QUESTION**: How do I write a typemap which gives me exactly the manually edited version of `_wrap_makeWidget` above, with no redundant calls to `makeWidget`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final answer, with great help from Mark Tolenen's answer and updates.  I am leaving the journey to this in the question unless moderators prefer me to compact the question in hindsight:

**Widget.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Widget
{
    int x;
    
    Widget() { x = 0; std::cout << "Widget::Widget()\n"; }
 
    // Note: non-virtual destructor is OK here
    ~Widget() { std::cout << "Widget::~Widget()\n"; }
};
 
void makeWidget(std::shared_ptr<Widget> &p);
```

**Widget.cpp**

```
#include "Widget.h"

void makeWidget(std::shared_ptr<Widget> &p)
  {
    p = std::make_shared<Widget>();
    p->x = 12;
}
```

**Widget.i**

```
// Great thanks to Mark Tolonen
%module Widget

%include <typemaps.i> // for OUTPUT
%include <std_shared_ptr.i>
%shared_ptr(Widget);

%{
#include "Widget.h"
%}

// Declare an input typemap that suppresses requiring any input
// and creates a temporary object that can be referenced.
%typemap(in, numinputs=0) std::shared_ptr<Widget>& (std::shared_ptr<Widget> tmp) %{
    $1 = &tmp;
%}

// Declare an output argument typemap updates the shared pointer,
// converts it to a Python object, and appends it to the return value.
%typemap(argout) std::shared_ptr<Widget>& %{
  {
    std::shared_ptr<  Widget > *smartresult = tmp1 ? new std::shared_ptr<  Widget >(tmp1) : 0;
    resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(smartresult), SWIGTYPE_p_std__shared_ptrT_Widget_t, SWIG_POINTER_OWN);
  }
%}

%include "Widget.h"
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Widget.h"
 
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Widget> p;
    makeWidget(p);
    std::cout << "x = " << p->x << "\n";
}
```

**test.py**

```
from Widget import *
x = makeWidget()
print(x)
y = makeWidget()
print(y)
```

**make.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash -x
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c Widget.cpp
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c main.cpp
g++ -O2 -fPIC Widget.o main.o -o widget
widget
swig -c++ -python -o Widget_wrap.cpp Widget.i
g++ -O2 -fPIC -I/home/catskills/anaconda3/envs/trader/include/python3.10 -c Widget_wrap.cpp
g++ -shared Widget.o Widget_wrap.o -o _Widget.so
python test.py
```

**Output of running make.sh**

```
$ make.sh
+ g++ -O2 -fPIC -c Widget.cpp
+ g++ -O2 -fPIC -c main.cpp
+ g++ -O2 -fPIC Widget.o main.o -o widget
+ widget
Widget::Widget()
x = 12
Widget::~Widget()
+ swig -c++ -python -o Widget_wrap.cpp Widget.i
+ g++ -O2 -fPIC -I/home/catskills/anaconda3/envs/trader/include/python3.10 -c Widget_wrap.cpp
+ g++ -shared Widget.o Widget_wrap.o -o _Widget.so
+ python test.py
Widget::Widget()
<Widget.Widget; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::shared_ptr< Widget > *' at 0x7f25e870ef30> >
Widget::Widget()
<Widget.Widget; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::shared_ptr< Widget > *' at 0x7f25e85791e0> >
Widget::~Widget()
Widget::~Widget()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have a working computer at the moment to test a working example, but you need the following in the SWIG .i file before you `%include` your header defining the functions that use your shared pointer.

The `OUTPUT` typemap can only be applied to a few basic types.  The typemaps below are my best guess without a computer to verify.

```cpp
%module test

%include <std_shared_ptr.i>
%shared_ptr(Widget);

%{
#include "Widget.h"
%}

// Declare an input typemap that suppresses requiring any input
// and creates a temporary object that can be referenced.
%typemap(in, numinputs=0) std::shared_ptr<Widget>& (std::shared_ptr<Widget> tmp) %{
    $1 = tmp;
%}

// Declare an output argument typemap updates the shared pointer,
// converts it to a Python object, and appends it to the return value.
%typemap(argout) std::shared_ptr<Widget>& %{
    makeWidget($1);
    PyObject* obj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(&$1, $descriptor(std::shared_ptr<Widget>*), 0)
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, obj);
%}

%include "Widget.h"
```

Comment: I am using Swig 4.0.  Even with shared_ptr declaration it is saying it wants a typemap.  Can you give an example typemap in this case?

Comment: @LarsEricson Updated with a best guess.  I forgot `OUTPUT` works for basic types only so your `%apply` won't work.

Comment: `makeS()` doesn't work, it doesn't take an argument.  There is a call to `makeS(*arg1)` in the generated wrapper where swig has declared `std::shared_ptr< Widget > *arg1 = 0 ;`.  I can't use `arg1` directly because it is not a `PyObject *`.  I don't know how to make a `PyObject *`.  I will add this to the question as an update, please help me refine.

Comment: @LarsEricson Try my updated code.  Not sure I have the `SWIG_NewPointerObj` correct.  I really need to fix my computer 

Comment: Almost there, I can compile and link but I get a segfault.  I will revise the example above. I am grateful for your help!

Comment: Final answer is a slight mod of your argout typemap: `    std::shared_ptr<  Widget > *smartresult = tmp1 ? new std::shared_ptr<  Widget >(tmp1) : 0;
    resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(smartresult), SWIGTYPE_p_std__shared_ptrT_Widget_t, SWIG_POINTER_OWN);`